# asp.net 6 and Blazor DI works on index.razor but not work in myPage.razor

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, blazor

i use dotnet 6 and visual studio 2022
i want inject IJSRuntime to my Page and Component
but IJSRuntime always null

this is page parent that use modal component

```
@page "/adminGroupRole"

<h3>AdminGroupRolePage</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=modalAddNewgroup.OpenModal>Add</button>

<ModalAddNewGroupRole @ref=modalAddNewgroup/>
```

and code behind of page parent

```
public partial class AdminGroupRolePage
    {
        [Inject] public IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }
        [Inject] public FinancialPortalDBAuth db { get; set; }
        ModalAddNewGroupRole modalAddNewgroup=new();
    }
```

i check that inject in default index works ...
why ???
my code is code behind the razor blazor page
this is my code

```
    public partial class ModalAddNewGroupRole
    {
        [Inject] public SweetAlert2Service SweetAlert2Service { get; set; }
        [Inject] public FinancialPortalDBAuth db { get; set; }
        [Inject] public IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

        DIMAuthGroup authGroupForAdd = new DIMAuthGroup();
        string ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public async Task OpenModal()
        {
            authGroupForAdd = new();
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("OpenModal", ID);
        }
}
```

[image]
[image]

exact inject in index.razor works perfect

inject on pare parent not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my wrong is i call OpenModal Method in razor page and blazor engine throw null exception for @ref=modalAddNewgroup and i force to new ModalAddNewGroupRole ...
this wrong new ModalAddNewGroupRole() break DI ...

i moved open modal in method in parent page and after click call open modal and as @Henk Holterman Sayed remove new ModalAddNewGroupRole() and all think is OK ...

my Wrong Code :

```
@page "/adminGroupRole"

<h3>AdminGroupRolePage</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=modalAddNewgroup.OpenModal>Add</button>

<ModalAddNewGroupRole @ref=modalAddNewgroup/>
```

Code Behind :

```
public partial class AdminGroupRolePage
    {
        [Inject] public IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }
        [Inject] public FinancialPortalDBAuth db { get; set; }
        ModalAddNewGroupRole modalAddNewgroup=new();
    }
```

My Correct Code :

```
@page "/adminGroupRole"

<h3>AdminGroupRolePage</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=OpenModalAddNewGroup>Add</button>

<ModalAddNewGroupRole @ref=modalAddNewgroup/>
```

Code Behind :

```
public partial class AdminGroupRolePage
    {
        [Inject] protected IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }
        [Inject] protected FinancialPortalDBAuth db { get; set; }
        ModalAddNewGroupRole modalAddNewgroup;

        async Task OpenModalAddNewGroup()
        {
            await modalAddNewgroup.OpenModal();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The reason this works is because now the Renderer is creating the `ModalAddNewGroupRole` component, doing the dependancy injection and assigning it to `modalAddNewgroup`.  You can't manually create instances of components and pass them to the renderer (page) to use.  The renderer manages the component process and lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

This relies on Property Injection. That is an active step somewhere in the creation process of ModalAddNewGroupRole.

So how do you get the instance where you call OpenModal() on?

You need a toplevel page that has `<ModalAddNewGroupRole />`  .

Doing your own `var modalAddNewGroupRole = new ModalAddNewGroupRole();` won't cut it.

Comment: i edited my question.. inject in page parent also not work

Comment: `ModalAddNewGroupRole modalAddNewgroup=new();` is wrong. Not clear if it is the core problem but do remove it.

Comment: chaged to ModalAddNewGroupRole modalAddNewgroup = new ModalAddNewGroupRole(); ... but not work

Comment: Don't change it, Remove it.

Comment: if i remove it so how i can access to it from code behind and call openModal ?

Comment: You have the `@ref=`

Comment: i cant understand ... please write example code for it ... thanks

Comment: if i remove new statement i receive null exception in _Host.cshtml File

Answer (score -3):

Try using this in your code behind

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
```

Comment: in visual studio 2022 automatically added for me